# Tiktok authentication for using api

Tags: api, web-applications, oauth, tiktok, tiktok-api

Can anybody tell me that is it necessary that tiktok webapp should be approved for getting access token cuz my app is under reviewed and when I go to authentication page for callback authorization after login it is showing error

I followed all the instructions that were given in there documentation but i am stucked at the call back authorization

Answer (score 0):

The status of your app should be **Live in production**. They usually give you feedback if there are any issues and in case it's declined. You have to make fixes accordingly to get the API functionality to work.

The reviewal process shouldn't take longer than 3 working days.